# Layout is copying over itself after updating when setting background colour programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I'm giving the option to set a custom background colour for an activity, and so I don't have the colour set in the layout xml. When a custom colour is set this works fine, however when using the default black, or when the custom colour option is off [the layout is copying over itself.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97wxp.jpg)

Here is the method

```
public void setCustomBackground() {

    View someView = findViewById(R.id.currentTextView);
    View root = someView.getRootView();

    if (customBackground) {

        if (timerIsInActive) {

            int activeColour;
            activeColour = sharedPreferences.getInt("activeColour", 0);
            root.setBackgroundColor(activeColour);

        } else if (timerIsInRelax) {


            int relaxColour;
            relaxColour = sharedPreferences.getInt("relaxColour", 0);
            root.setBackgroundColor(relaxColour);

        }
    } else {

        root.setBackgroundColor(0);

    }

}
```

I've tried setting the colour in the xml layout, which stops the issue, but also stops the ability to change the colours.

Is this some bug with the SDK, or am I doing something stupid?

EDIT: I should also mention that when the custom colour is set as black, there is no issue with that either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure exactly why the issue was happening in the first place, however changing

```
root.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

to

```
root.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

appears to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Based on the android documentation here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#TRANSPARENT you are setting the background color to transparent when you set it to 0. The layout is adding itself to the existing layout and showing the top layout with transparency which in turn is showing what is behind that new layout. If you are going to set the value as constant then black is -16777216 based on the documentation